# GPS Co-Ordinates fails during cloudy weather

Tags: android, gps

I am trying to Fetch GPS continuously every minute using Android Code. When it clean sky its works very fine. But sometimes when there are lots of clouds i am not able to get the latitude & longitude. in such case how should I get GPS Co-Ordinates ?

Comment: You should figure out how to cope when GPS coordinates are not available, i.e. fallback gracefully. There will always be conditions where geolocation is not possible.

Comment: I know that thing, but what should I do in that case ?

Comment: Not knowing your application I am unable to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use WiFi location and Cell Tower location as fallback:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

```
private static final int TWO_MINUTES = 1000 * 60 * 2;

/** Determines whether one Location reading is better than the current Location fix
  * @param location  The new Location that you want to evaluate
  * @param currentBestLocation  The current Location fix, to which you want to compare the new one
  */
protected boolean isBetterLocation(Location location, Location currentBestLocation) {
    if (currentBestLocation == null) {
        // A new location is always better than no location
        return true;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is newer or older
    long timeDelta = location.getTime() - currentBestLocation.getTime();
    boolean isSignificantlyNewer = timeDelta > TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isSignificantlyOlder = timeDelta < -TWO_MINUTES;
    boolean isNewer = timeDelta > 0;

    // If it's been more than two minutes since the current location, use the new location
    // because the user has likely moved
    if (isSignificantlyNewer) {
        return true;
    // If the new location is more than two minutes older, it must be worse
    } else if (isSignificantlyOlder) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check whether the new location fix is more or less accurate
    int accuracyDelta = (int) (location.getAccuracy() - currentBestLocation.getAccuracy());
    boolean isLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 0;
    boolean isMoreAccurate = accuracyDelta < 0;
    boolean isSignificantlyLessAccurate = accuracyDelta > 200;

    // Check if the old and new location are from the same provider
    boolean isFromSameProvider = isSameProvider(location.getProvider(),
            currentBestLocation.getProvider());

    // Determine location quality using a combination of timeliness and accuracy
    if (isMoreAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isLessAccurate) {
        return true;
    } else if (isNewer && !isSignificantlyLessAccurate && isFromSameProvider) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/** Checks whether two providers are the same */
private boolean isSameProvider(String provider1, String provider2) {
    if (provider1 == null) {
      return provider2 == null;
    }
    return provider1.equals(provider2);
}
```

Also, check out this post...both answers are applicable: [Android: GPS fallback from fine to coarse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554569/android-gps-fallback-from-fine-to-coarse)